# how to take a value from CSV, increment it and save it back using java

Tags: java, csv

This is my csv file:

```
pencil,1
sharpener,1
eraser,1
pen,1
```

what I want to do is when I pass 'add pencil' as a command line argument then the first line changes to `pencil,2`

```
if (args.length == 2 & "add".equals(args[0])){
                String tempFile = "C:/Users/hayth/eclipse-workspace/pencilbox/src/pencilbox/tmp.csv";
                File oldFile = new File(path);
                File newFile = new File(tempFile);
                String item = ""; String quantity = "";
                try {
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile,true);
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
                    x = new Scanner(new File(path));
                    x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
                    
                    
                    while(x.hasNext()){
                        item = x.next();
                        quantity = x.next();
                        if(item.equals(args[1])) {
                            quantity = quantity+1;
                            pw.println(item + "," + quantity);
                        }
                        else {
                            pw.println(item + "," + quantity);
                        }
                    }
```

currently this executes like this:

```
pencil,1
1
sharpener,1

eraser,1

pen,1
```

when I converted to integer then incremented and then tried to compile it gave me this:

```
"ava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
        at pencilbox.pencilBox.main(pencilBox.java:47)
```

this is how I did the conversion:

```
while(x.hasNext()){
                        item = x.next();
                        quantity = x.next();
                        if(item.equals(args[1])) {
                            int i = Integer.parseInt(quantity);
                            i=i+1;
                            quantity = String.valueOf(i);
                            pw.println(item + "," + quantity);
                        }
                        else {
                            pw.println(item + "," + quantity);
                        }
```

I've just started with java. suggest how I can overcome this problem.

Comment: Note that the exception tells you most of your problem: the STRING "1   " (with those many trailing spaces cant be parsed as number. Sure because "1   " isnt a number ;-). So a **first** step would be to use `parseInt(quantity.trim())` as `trim()` removes such trailing spaces. But of course, the "better" answer is to follow all the advice in the answer you got below, and to make sure that your `quantity` String variable comes back from the scanner without any trailing whitespaces.

Comment: thanks for the tip it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've commented some parts that lead to problems. Especially (3) and (4) will answer your question.

```
if (args.length == 2 & "add".equals(args[0])){                // (1)
    String tempFile = ".../tmp.csv";
    File oldFile = new File(path);
    File newFile = new File(tempFile);
    String item = ""; String quantity = "";
    try {                                                     // (2)
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile,true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
        x = new Scanner(new File(path));
        x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");                              // (3)
                
                
        while(x.hasNext()){
            item = x.next();
            quantity = x.next();                              // (4)
            if(item.equals(args[1])) {
                quantity = quantity+1;
                pw.println(item + "," + quantity);
            } else {
                pw.println(item + "," + quantity);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

1. use short circuit evaluation (`&&`, `||`) instead, to avoid side-effects. For your example this is fine, but consider an expression like `if(args != null & args[0].equals(""))` which would result in a NullPointerException, because even while args is `null`, `args[0]` will be evaluated.
2. Java offers you "try-with-resources", which will take care of closing used resources. (In your case, you would have to close the Writer-Objects after your `try`-block.

   ```
   try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile, true);
         BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
         PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
         Scanner x = new Scanner(new File(path));) {...}
   ```
3. `\n` is the Unix Line Separator character. It's better to use `System.lineSeperator()` instead of `\n`, because it will yield the system specific line seperator character.

   ```
   x.useDelimiter("[," + System.lineSeperator() + "]");
   ```
4. `x.nextInt()` will yield the next IntValue as an `int` and avoid the NumberFormatException, that arises, because `x.next()` will include a line separator which cannot be cast into an Integer.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning `quantity.trim()` too.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions, since I'm just starting with java it'll prove useful to know the best practices.